# Recreate/Use the default iPhone Photo app save menu

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, ios7

I want to save a photo with the same options given by the default iPhone photo app as seen in this picture:
[image: iPhone photo app send menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `UIActivityViewController`. You can create a `UIActivityViewController`, pass it an image, or the URL to an image, and optionally tell it to exclude certain activities that you don't want to appear. Then, present it, as you would any other viewController.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ myImage ] applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];
activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
    // handle completion
};
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.